# JOGL javaw.exe remains running after application is closed

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have a simple java application that uses JOGL. When I run it from eclipse, and then close the application window, javaw.exe remains running. Here is the the relevant code:

```
public class App {
    private Display mDisplay;
    private Shell mShell;
    private GL4 mGl;
    private int mProgramId;
    private int mVsId;
    private int mFsId;

    // ...

    public void start() {
        if (!initialize()) {
            return;
        }

        while (!mShell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!mDisplay.readAndDispatch()) {
                mDisplay.sleep();
            }
        }

        destroy();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mDisplay = new Display();
        mShell = new Shell(mDisplay);

        // some SWT and opengl initialization code, which is irrelevant for this issue
        // (at least I think so)
        // getting GLProfile, GLContext, GL4 etc.

        final String vsText = ResourceManager.getShaderText(vsPath);
        final String fsText = ResourceManager.getShaderText(fsPath);

        mVsId = mGl.glCreateShader(GL4.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        mFsId = mGl.glCreateShader(GL4.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        mGl.glShaderSource(mVsId, 1, new String[] { vsText }, null, 0);
        mGl.glCompileShader(mVsId);

        mGl.glShaderSource(mFsId, 1, new String[] { fsText }, null, 0);
        mGl.glCompileShader(mFsId);

        mProgramId = mGl.glCreateProgram();

        mGl.glAttachShader(mProgramId, mFsId);
        mGl.glAttachShader(mProgramId, mVsId);

        // bind a constant attribute location for positions of vertices
        mGl.glBindAttribLocation(mProgramId, 0, "in_Position");
        // bind another constant attribute location, this time for color
        mGl.glBindAttribLocation(mProgramId, 1, "in_Color");
        mGl.glLinkProgram(mProgramId);

        // here error code is 0x0 (no error)
        int error = mGl.glGetError();

        mShell.open();

        return true;
    }

    private void destroy() {

        // here error code is 0x502 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
        int error = mGl.glGetError();

        mGl.glDetachShader(mProgramId, mFsId);
        mGl.glDetachShader(mProgramId, mVsId);

        mGl.glDeleteShader(mFsId);
        mGl.glDeleteShader(mVsId);
        mGl.glDeleteProgram(mProgramId);

        mDisplay.dispose();
    }
}
```

I commented out all rendering code and most other opengl/JOGL related calls (besides getting GLProfile, GLContext, GL4 and everything listed in this sample) and this problem persists.

Generally, the application works fine, shaders compile and link without problem (I used validation which I didn't display in this sample) and it displays what it needs to. The only problem is that javaw.exe remains running after I close the application window (by pressing the x in the corner of the window).

This issue is removed only if I comment out `mGl.glCompileShader(mVsId);` and subsequent lines. If I leave this line, javaw.exe will remain running, so I guess the problem is related to shader initialization/destruction code.

Also, glGetError() returns 0 (no error) at the end of initialize() and 0x502 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) at the beginning of destroy(). There is only the main loop in between and no opengl calls that I know of, since, for testing, I commented out all rendering code.

Any ideas?

**Edit 2012-10-03:**

I still don't know what the problem is, but since I updated my graphic card drivers, 'javaw.exe' terminates as it should after application is closed. I have AMD Radeon HD 6870. My current driver version is 8.982 from 2012-07-27, and I can't remember what the last version was, but I believe it was from january 2011 or so.

However, glGetError() still returns 0x502 at the beginning of destroy, so I guess there is still something wrong.

Comment: Hi, take a look to this [sample](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Jogl_Tutorial#Hello_Triangle)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use JOGL from jogamp.org, pls use either our [SWT GLCanvas](http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl.git;a=blob;f=src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/swt/TestNewtCanvasSWTGLn.java;hb=HEAD)
or our [NEWTCanvasSWT](http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl.git;a=blob;f=src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/swt/TestNewtCanvasSWTGLn.java;hb=HEAD).
The latter is preferred due to custom GLCapabilities, pls check API doc.
This given plus you are doing everything SWT related on the SWT thread (read 
linked unit tests), IMHO it should work - at least our unit tests.

Since you mentioned after an update (GPU/driver) your troubles ceased to exist,
it might have been a driver problem.

Now to your GL error. Trace GL errors can be simply done by setting the system property 'jogl.debug.DebugGL', i.e. on the commandline "-Djogl.debug.DebugGL".
This will install the debug pipeline for your GL object automatically and checks for GL error, which will throw an GLException if appear.

You can also trace via the property 'jogl.debug.TraceGL'.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response :). I am using org.eclipse.swt.opengl.GLCanvas, it is used by some example I found so I used it as well. I'll try the ones you mentioned. Also 'jogl.debug.DebugGL' does nothing in my case while I still get that error code 0x502. I'm a novice in java so I might be setting it wrong - this is what I do at beginning of main Properties props = System.getProperties(); props.setProperty("jogl.debug.DebugGL", "true");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but may help someone I guess so I'm gonna share it here. Keep in mind I'm just a hobbyist getting started in Java SWT.

I made a simple application in Eclipse IDE using the Java SWT library. I made a ''Quit'' button in my main Window shell that when pushed calls this :

```
    quitBtn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            shell.getDisplay().dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

After exporting the .jar file to Desktop, I converted it to a .exe file with LaunchJ4 wrapper and check the "Allow only a single instance of the application" in the Single instance tab using the singleR3XPlayer mutex.

When I would close the .exe file with the "Quit" button, everything was fine and the javaw.exe would terminates. But when I closed the shell with the X button on the top-right window, javaw.exe would remains running. I figured that out when I tried to delete the .exe file (Windows "Used file, still open in Java(TM) Platform SE binary, close the file and retry" type of error pop-up) and as I couldn't open another instance of the file after closing it with the X button (because of the Single instance mutex). Also, multiple instances of javaw.exe would remains running if I would execute a few of the .jar file (even after closing them, but only with the X and not the "Quit" button).

I figured out closing the window with the X button would only dispose of the shell and not exit the program. But pressing the "Quit" button would because it called System.exit(0). So I did this :

```
    // SWT Event Loop
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
            display.sleep();
    }

    // To make sure javaw.exe terminates when Window is closed
    if (shell.isDisposed()) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Hence, after my SWT Event loop is done (shell.isDisposed() == true), I made sure System.exit(0) would be called. This way, javaw.exe is terminated either way.

I don't know how SWT works and I don't know if that's the proper way to do it but it ensures javaw.exe is terminated once the application closes.

Hope that helps.